# Gordans lemma seperation

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $A$ be an $m × n$ matrix. Recall that Gordan’s lemma states that the
system
$$\{d : Ad < 0\}$$ 
is inconsistent if and only if the system
$$λ ≥ 0 ∈ R ^m , λ \not= 0, A ^T λ = 0$$
is consistent.

---

1. Show that the consistency of the second system is equivalent to the
   statement that $0 ∈ C$
2. Use a separation argument to prove that $\{d : Ad < 0\} = ∅$ if and
   only if $ 0 \notin C$, thereby proving Gordan’s lemma

   ## Proof so far

$\Rightarrow$ Let $C$ be the convex hull of the rows of $A$, that is, $C = co(a_1 , . . . , a_m ) ⊆ E$,where $a_i$ is the ith row of $A$. Suppose the second system is consistent. We want to show that $0 \in C$.
If $A^{T}=[a_1,a_2,...,a_m]$.
Then $A^{T}\lambda=\sum_{i=1}^{m}a_i\lambda_i=0$.
Therefore $0 \in C$

Comment: I need help proving these staments